# Global variables nullified after function call

Tags: php, codeigniter, paypal

I've built an application in codeigniter that requires paypal checkout integration.

I've added the paypal nvp sample code to the codeigniter application, the files have been placed in the /third-party/ folder.

In my controller I have a method that handles the form submission. At this stage I require ReviewOrder.php, which follows the sample code example.

```
public function paymentOption()
{
    if( $this->input->post() )
    {
        require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/../application/third_party/paypal/reviewOrder.php');
    }

}
```

However, when I submit the form, I get lots of warnings / notices and I've whittled this down to the hash_call() function in CallerService.php in particular the global variables are all being nullified inside this function.

I have var_dump-ed the variables above the function and the correct values are being output to the screen.

I have also tested the paypal nvp sample code outside of codeigniter and this all works as intended, so my development environment is fine.

I've looked in many forums etc for global variables being nullified, but none seem to match my exact issue.

To view the paypal nvp php code samples - go here https://github.com/GeorgeOld/Paypal-NVP-PHP-code-examples

At this stage I am only concerned with **ReviewOrder.php** and **CallerService.php**

Comment: What's the content of reviewOrder.php? Anyway, you might use session class instead of global variables

Comment: Hi Damien, I have updated my post with links to the sample code. Here's the link for ReviewOrder.php https://github.com/GeorgeOld/Paypal-NVP-PHP-code-examples/blob/master/ReviewOrder.php I haven't made any drastic changes to this file in my application.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I had a look at the code and 2 solutions comes to my mind:

1. You could either change global variables into $_SESSION indexes (php native or CI's session elements) or, better yet, build a cunstom library that wraps all you need from those files making the necessary adaptation in order to work without problems in a CI environment. I'll go for this second choice, even if it requires some work in order to port them correctly in the OOP structure. For some guidance check the manual on [creating libraries](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/creating_libraries.html); it's pretty easy and makes your code easier to mantain and follow.
2. You could abandon the current solution and search for alternatives among codes already adapted to Codeigniter. A couple gooleing led me to this resource: [CI PayPal NVP Library](http://www.leonbarrett.com/code/paypal/), that looks nice and clean (but haven't analysed it); even if seems to be meant for CI 1.7 it might not need much tweaking in order to use it on the latest release.
   You could give it a try or search CI forum for others libraries of the same kind.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I have looked into the CI PayPal NVP library but unfortunately there is very limited documentation. I may do as you suggest and adapt the code samples to OOP.